# TCA Icon overlay in typo3 backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, typo3-tca

I’m working on an extension where I synchronise some data to another database and I wanted to show this in the backend using a TCA icon overlay. Sadly I could not find out how to do this. I thought about using ‘ctrl’=>‘typeicon_classes’ (using the state field of my table to choose an icon), this works for the default (non synchronised element) but I cannot figure out how to set an overlay. Any idea on how to do this?

My TCA configuration looks like this:

```
'ctrl' => [
    ...
    'typeicon_column' => 'state',
    'typeicon_classes' => [
        'new' => 'mimetypes-x-content-login',
        'synced' => 'mimetypes-x-content-login-overlay-approved',
    ]
],
```

The "synced" part does not work as expected. What I would expect is to either add the overlay at the end of the icon or by adding it with a whitespace but both did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I really just need this in the TYPO3 backend, the obvious solution for frontend is to use fluid or PHP but I don't think this suits the TYPO3 Backend list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your icon files.
Given your icon files are named *content_login.svg* and *content_login_overlay_approved.svg* located in directory */Resources/Public/Icons/* you can register these in *ext_localconf.php* as following:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    $icons = [
        'mimetypes-x-content-login' => 'content_login.svg',
        'mimetypes-x-content-login-overlay-approved' => 'content_login_overlay_approved.svg',
    ];
    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
    foreach ($icons as $identifier => $path) {
        $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
            $identifier,
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
            ['source' => 'EXT:YOUREXTENSIONNANME/Resources/Public/Icons/' . $path]
        );
    }
}
```

Adapt *yourextensionname*

Comment: Ok, so I have to take the existing svg icon from TYPO3 and add the existing overlay SVG and make my new svg file, right?